# How to perform POST requests to a REST webservice?

Tags: web-services, rest, post

I have a RESTful webservice, in which I have written a method which receives `POST` requests.

I am trying to access that method via the URL `http://localhost:8091/prjctname/post`.

But its throwing the following error:

> *HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported*
>   *type:* Status report
>   *message:* Request method 'GET' not supported
>   *description:* The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource

Below is the code snippet.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Produces("application/json")
@ResponseBody 
public String createUser(@RequestBody PCDBean bean, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String username = null;
    String password = null;
    System.out.println("inside post method");

    String result = service.getCustomer(username, password);
    if(result != null) {
        return username + password;
    } else {
        return "failure";
    }
}
```

Comment: You've received a [**great answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35842466/290085) to your question.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) it  if it's helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Explaining the 405 error

You are performing a `GET` request to an endpoint that only supports `POST` requests. In this situation, the expected result is a `405` error:

> [**6.5.5.  405 Method Not Allowed**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)
>
> The `405` (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method
> received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not
> supported by the target resource. [...]

### Picking the right tool

I guess you are trying to access the endpoint using the **browser address bar**. However, when typing the resource URL in the browser address bar, you are performing a `GET` request. That's the default behavior of the browser. *Deal with it*.

Hence, the browser address bar won't give you much flexibility to test a REST API, once you only can perform `GET` requests from it.

To test a REST API, you should use the **right tools**. They will give you the ability to perform requests using [all the HTTP methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) (including `POST`), set [request headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5) and other features that are not available in the browser address bar.

Just listing a few:

- [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/)
- [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) (Chrome extension)
- [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) (Chrome extension)

Comment: Why hasn't this fine answer been [**accepted**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215)?

Answer (score 0):

The real issue in my case was that my text wasn't exactly the one expected in the server. The object had a spelling error. Should be exactly 
"{\n"+"\"jobName\":\"MOVE_TO_PICK_POSITION\"\n"+"}";
and I was using something else.

The 405 error message made me waste a lot of time since it made me think that there was some problem with my POST request.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the browser to accept a post request, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="login" method="post">
    name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```